# Where is the junk folder that I created in Thunderbird on an ubuntu system?

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird, mail, mail-server, spamassassin

I am using Thunderbird on Windows 7 to fetch emails from my ubuntu server.

I found my mails being stored in `/var/qmail/mailnames/domain.de/info/Maildir/cur` but neither in `/var/qmail/mailnames/domain.de/info/Maildir/cur` nor in `/var/qmail/mailnames/domain.de/info/Maildir` there is a Junk folder or Spam folder.

My goal is to use `sa-learn` with the junk folder to learn.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely place : `/var/qmail/mailnames/domain.de/info/Maildir/.Junk/cur`
Files/directories with "leading dot" may be not displayed (hidden) in some file managers.

[Maildir++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir#Maildir.2B.2B)